# Cannot get any results from ElasticSearch with JDBC River

Tags: plugins, jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I cannot figure out how to use this plugin at all. 
I am running this `curl`:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/faycare_kids/_meta' -d '{
  "jdbc":{
      "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver",
      "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/faycare",
      "user" : "faycare",
      "password" : "password",
      "strategy" : "simple",
      "poll" : "5s",
      "scale" : 0,
      "autocommit" : true,
      "fetchsize" : 10,
      "index" : "faycare",
      "type" : "kid",
      "max_rows" : 0,
      "max_retries" : 3,
      "max_retries_wait" : "10s",
      "sql"   : "SELECT kid.id as _id,kid.first_name,kid.last_name FROM kid;"
  }
}'
```

It returns:

```
{"ok":true,"_index":"_river","_type":"faycare_kids","_id":"_meta","_version":1}
```

**How do I search/fetch/see my data?**

**How do I know if anything is indexed?**

I tried so many things:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_river/faycare_kids/_search?pretty&q=*'
```

This gives me info about the `_river`

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/faycare/kid/_search?pretty&q=*'
```

This tells me: `"error" : "IndexMissingException[[faycare] missing]"`

I am running `sudo service elasticsearch start` to run it in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you setting up your river. You specifying and index and type where the river should bulk indexing records in the wrong place.

The proper way of doing this would be this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/faycare_kids/_meta' -d '{
  "type" : "jdbc",
  "jdbc":{
      "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver",
      "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/faycare",
      "user" : "faycare",
      "password" : "password",
      "strategy" : "simple",
      "poll" : "5s",
      "scale" : 0,
      "autocommit" : true,
      "fetchsize" : 10,
      "max_rows" : 0,
      "max_retries" : 3,
      "max_retries_wait" : "10s",
      "sql"   : "SELECT kid.id as _id,kid.first_name,kid.last_name FROM kid;"
  },
  "index":{
      "index" : "faycare",
      "type" : "kid"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, I would install [elasticsearch head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) it can be super useful for checking on your cluster.

You can get stats for all indices:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_status'
```

You can check if an index exists:

```
curl -XHEAD 'http://localhost:9200/myindex'
```

You should be able to search all indices like this:

```
  curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_all/_search?q=*'
```

If nothing shows up, your rivers are probably not working, I would check your logs to see if any errors appear.

Comment: I agree with mconlin, elasticsearch head is a great for having an overview of your indices, the data and their status.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all of your help. The `elastic-head` did give me some insight. Apparently I just had something wrong with my `JSON` For some reason when I changed my JSON to this it worked:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
      "type" : "jdbc",
      "jdbc" : {
          "driver" : "org.postgresql.Driver",
          "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/faycare",
          "user" : "faycare",
          "password" : "hatpants",
          "index" : "jdbc",
          "type" : "jdbc"
          "sql"   : "SELECT kid.id as _id,kid.first_name,kid.last_name FROM kid;"
      }
 }'
```

I am not sure what specifically needed to be changed to make this work, but it does now work. I am guessing that it is the outer `jdbc` needed to be added. I am guessing I can change the inner `index` and `type`.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a quick post on using this plugin, hopefully in can give you a little more insight - the post is located [here](http://blog.smeef.co.uk/mysql-jdbc-river/).